# Tab bar in a View instead of Window

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to use tab bar in a view instead of window? Seems everyone add tab bar to their window.

My first screen is a login screen, which doesn't need tab bar. 
After user login, it change to the second screen, which contain a tabbar.

Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend you load your tabbar, then check for login credentials. If not found, showModal window to prompt for New Registration or Login Credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Everything in an iPhone app is displayed in a view, which is then displayed by a window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.  You can use interface builder to add a UITabBar to whatever view you want.  The view controller for the view should then implement the protocol UITabBarControllerDelegate to handle selections of tab bar items.

It's worth having a look at the template tab bar project that you can create in XCode to understand this.  The view containing the tab bar is owned by the view controller - it's this view that gets added to the window in the application delegate -

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

    // Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window
    [window addSubview:tabBarController.view];
}
```